# Proof of equivalence relation on set.

Tags: number-theory, equivalence-relations

I'm new to the whole relations topic and stumbled upon a problem.

I know that an equivalence relation is a relation that is symmetric, transitive, reflexive, (and not usually anti-symmetric).

But then how do we prove that for a equivalence relation R on a set X, and if a,b ∈ X,

1. a∈ [[a]] <--equivalence class
2. [[a]] = [[b]] iff (a,b) ∈ R
3. [[a]] ∩ [[b]] = 0 iff (a,b) ∉ R

?

Comment: An equivalence relation is reflexive, symmetric, transitive, and **not** (usually) anti-symmetric.

Comment: These questions where thoroughly answered of this site before.

Answer (score 0):

- $a\in [[a]]$ is easy to prove. You can see that since $aRa$, $a\in [[a]]$.
- $[[a]] = [[b]]$ iff $(a,b) ∈ R$ is easy to prove. If $(a,b)\in R$, then $[[a]]=[[b]]$. If $[[a]]=[[b]]$, then $aRb$, i.e., $(a,b)\in R$.
- $[[a]]\cap [[b]]=\emptyset$ iff $(a,b)\not\in R$. If $(a,b)\not\in R$, then $[[a]]\cap[[b]]=\emptyset$ by definition. If $[[a]]\neq[[b]]$, then $a\not R b$, i.e., $[[a]]\cap[[b]]=\emptyset$.